# Route between components under the same lazy module without activating the canActivateChild

Tags: angular, angular-routing, canactivatechild

I have a component named FirstComponent and its location is in /hub/first. The hub-routing module has a check for each route and looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivateChild: [HubGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'firstComponent,
```

This means that every '/hub' route will be checked by the HubGurad CanActivate function.

I also have a guard for the first component route that checks and conditions and if it doesn't exist it redirects it to '/hub/secondComponent'.

The problem that I am facing is that I can see that although I am routing within 2 components under the same HubModule the "canActivate" function is called again. Is there a way that I can route from the first component to the second one without reactivating the CanActivateChild guard?

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `canActivate` instead of `canActivateChild` guard. It check this route branch once you enter.